# Google App Inventor - Packaging App leads to server error performing build

Tags: packaging, app-inventor

It's a simple app with only a few blocks of code, a few PNG images... Can't seem to package it in different computers or browsers. Any ideas? I can upload the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I completely rebuilt the app following the original blocks and it worked. Maybe somehow the original app got corrupted.